# Возможно ли делать запись звука во время разговора?

Tags: android, звукозапись

Подскажите, возможно ли делать запись звука во время разговора на андройде 9+. Запись работает, но когда я звоню естественно система это все блокирует и звук не пишется. Возможно ли как то это сделать?
Код простой:

```
try {
        releaseRecorder();

        File outFile = new File(fileName);
        if (outFile.exists()) {
            outFile.delete();
        }
        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(fileName);
        try {
            mediaRecorder.prepare();
            mediaRecorder.start();
        }
        catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```